# Zariski topology: Is the complementary set of a circle connected?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is the complementary set of a circle connected or disconnected in the Zariski topology? I had a similar question to this when I just started algebraic geometry however I'm more familiar with the relative topology now & think it is disconnected but I don't exactly remember the answer I was given so I have to ask.

Comment: Any open subspace of an inducible space is irreducible.

Comment: Do you mean Zariski topology of $\Bbb A^2_{\Bbb R}$, or do you mean Zariski topology of $\Bbb A^1_{\Bbb C}$?

Comment: Well for the real part of $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^{2}$. I thought the interior of the circle and exterior for some reason could be two different open subsets when they are the same. Then I read about for any two open subsets their intersection is non empty in irreducible space. So it apparently is connected right? So what can you tell me about for $\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^{1}$ that is different?